# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query when running query on table

Tags: mysql

My system crashed last night. At first, I couldn't get mysql up and running. To resolve the issue, I did the following:

mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile* ~

I could then start mysql. However, when I run the following simple query on a particular table, I get an error:

```
mysql> select * from posts;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Queries on other tables work fine without an error. This is an innoDB table and database. There is nothing particularly large about this table with about 14,000 rows. The error happens instantly upon executing it.

Comment: What's really odd is I can do `select COL_NAME from posts where 1` on all of the individual columns and the data outputs just fine.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, there is one column that also throws an error. posts.content. It's a fairly large field of type MEDIUMTEXT.

Comment: I jacked up the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 256M but still having issues.

Comment: When I do a very simple query for run row like with `select content from posts where id = 998780123551706` I still get the error.

Comment: I ended up restoring the table from a backup taken 1/2 hour earlier. I'm going to assume the problem was corruption.